# R on GPU in the cloud

Tags: r, tensorflow, amazon-ec2, gpu, regression

I have to run regression daily on a data set that consists of 6 million rows and over 20 columns. I would like to speed up the computation and move it into the cloud. Is [tensorflow.rstudio](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tools/gpu.html) currently the best option for my purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well:

```
R> nr <- 6e6 
R> nc <- 20   
R> M <- matrix(rnorm(nr*nc), nr, nc)          
R> y <- runif(nr)                               
R> system.time(b1 <- lm.fit(M, y))          
   user  system elapsed                 
 18.219  10.046   3.169 
R>
```

And if we want a fancier `lm()`-alike but fast approach:

```
R> system.time(b2 <- RcppArmadillo::fastLm(M, y))        
   user  system elapsed 
 10.028   9.248   3.733 
R>
```

where we can look at results easily in the normal form:

```
R> summary(b2)

Call:
fastLm.default(X = M, y = y)

Residuals:
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.0028683  0.2496700  0.4996900  0.7498700  1.0030000 

        Estimate     StdErr t.value p.value  
 [1,]  1.138e-04  2.355e-04   0.483  0.6290  
 [2,]  3.637e-04  2.356e-04   1.543  0.1228  
 [3,]  2.602e-04  2.355e-04   1.105  0.2692  
 [4,]  6.760e-05  2.357e-04   0.287  0.7743  
 [5,]  2.440e-04  2.357e-04   1.035  0.3005  
 [6,]  1.230e-04  2.356e-04   0.522  0.6017  
 [7,] -1.239e-04  2.356e-04  -0.526  0.5990  
 [8,] -9.908e-05  2.356e-04  -0.420  0.6741  
 [9,] -1.633e-04  2.356e-04  -0.693  0.4882  
[10,] -3.994e-04  2.357e-04  -1.695  0.0901 .
[11,] -2.056e-05  2.356e-04  -0.087  0.9304  
[12,] -1.335e-04  2.356e-04  -0.567  0.5709  
[13,] -9.811e-05  2.356e-04  -0.416  0.6772  
[14,]  3.083e-04  2.356e-04   1.308  0.1907  
[15,] -9.598e-06  2.356e-04  -0.041  0.9675  
[16,]  1.781e-04  2.355e-04   0.756  0.4494  
[17,]  4.247e-05  2.355e-04   0.180  0.8569  
[18,]  1.425e-04  2.358e-04   0.604  0.5457  
[19,]  5.302e-05  2.356e-04   0.225  0.8219  
[20,]  1.735e-04  2.357e-04   0.736  0.4616  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.577 on 5999980 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 2.14e-06,   Adjusted R-squared: -1.19e-06
R>
```

So there really is no problem.  That took *under four seconds* on my (arguably half-decent and recent) machine at home.  Why "cloud"?  Why "tensorflow"?  Do you understand that tensorflow is *very demanding and slow* whereas a regression is a single linear projections (which happens over multiple cores here in a totally *automagic* fashion)?  No custom software but plain Debian/Ubuntu packages (which I happen to involved with).

I'd be happy to act as your consultant if I get cut of the savings over AWS or Azure...  And I am only half kidding.